# Yelp line is too wide for man pages

Tags: 19.04, manpage, yelp

I am generally using `yelp` (the life preserver icon on the desktop) to view system *man* pages. After I open `yelp`, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and enter `man:man` for example to view the man page for the `man` command.

This works OK. However, the line width is different on each of my Ubuntu installations. For example, the first (physical) line of `man man` page's **DESCRIPTION** section in `yelp` is like this:

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Virtual Machine):

> man is the system's manual pager. Each page argument given to man is normally the name of

Ubuntu 19.04 (Virtual Machine):

> man is the system's manual pager. Each page argument given to man is normally the name of a program, utility or function. The manual page associated with each of these arguments is

Ubuntu 19.04 (Physical Machine):

> man is the system's manual pager. Each page argument given to man is normally the name of a program, utility or function. The manual page associated with each of these arguments is then found and displayed.    A section, if

As you see, in my desktop (physical machine) man pages are formatted very wide. You can view the page correctly only when the `yelp` window is maximized. However, when you set it to something half of the screen width, the lines are wrapped and the physical line breaks occur at odd places which is very confusing.

How, can I set `yelp` to display man pages with say 80-character physical lines?

---

***Note:*** Setting the `MANWIDTH` environment variable, works in `man` command line; but, does not make any change in `yelp`. For example, the command `MANWIDTH=80 yelp man:man` still displays wide lines as described above.

Comment: In newer versions of `yelp` and Ubuntu, setting the `MANWIDTH` environment variable _does_ make the `yelp` command to use the specified line width.